# Wacom crashes computer after 18.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, tablet, wacom, graphics-tablet

I encounter a big issue with my computer since I upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, if I try to use my Wacom tablet, the computer freezes when restarts.

To sum up:
- Wacom Intuos Art Pen & Touch
- I was on 16.04, my graphics tablet worked
- after 18.04 upgrade (upgrade was proposed at the start of Ubuntu) it doesn't work at all, and worse restart Ubuntu.

I would like to either :
- correct this issue if known
- or re-install completely my Wacom tablet, but I'm not sure how to uninstall first.

Did you already encounter this issue?
Could you help me?
Thank you

Regards

**EDIT**

Here the logs I found in /var/log/:

```
kern.log
---------------------------------------------
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop kernel: [  706.763836] gnome-shell[3578]: segfault at 758127e0 ip b6b612a6 sp bfb5f868 error 4 in libc-2.27.so[b6aca000+1d5000]
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop kernel: [  713.519783] gnome-shell[4626]: segfault at 758127e0 ip b6ba22a6 sp bfd59dc8 error 4 in libc-2.27.so[b6b0b000+1d5000]
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop kernel: [  713.650841] rfkill: input handler enabled
---------------------------------------------
apport.log
---------------------------------------------
ERROR: apport (pid 4622) Wed Sep 12 23:48:03 2018: called for pid 3578, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 4622) Wed Sep 12 23:48:03 2018: executable: /usr/bin/gnome-shell (command line "/usr/bin/gnome-shell")
ERROR: apport (pid 4622) Wed Sep 12 23:48:03 2018: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 4622) Wed Sep 12 23:48:03 2018: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
ERROR: apport (pid 4670) Wed Sep 12 23:48:10 2018: called for pid 4626, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 4670) Wed Sep 12 23:48:10 2018: executable: /usr/bin/gnome-shell (command line "/usr/bin/gnome-shell")
ERROR: apport (pid 4670) Wed Sep 12 23:48:10 2018: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 4670) Wed Sep 12 23:48:10 2018: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
---------------------------------------------
auth.log
---------------------------------------------
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:4 (system bus name :1.137, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale fr_FR.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:4 (system bus name :1.185 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale fr_FR.UTF-8)
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:4 (system bus name :1.185, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale fr_FR.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user ***
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd-logind[747]: Removed session 4.
---------------------------------------------
syslog
---------------------------------------------
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop kernel: [  706.763836] gnome-shell[3578]: segfault at 758127e0 ip b6b612a6 sp bfb5f868 error 4 in libc-2.27.so[b6aca000+1d5000]
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop gnome-session[3416]: gnome-session-binary[3416]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop gnome-session-binary[3416]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID vendor "SAM", prod id 772
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz eP)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Sep 12 23:48:03 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (--) NOUVEAU(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
Sep 12 23:48:04 ***-desktop gsd-media-keys[3731]: g_variant_get_va: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Sep 12 23:48:04 ***-desktop gsd-media-keys[3731]: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4626]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop dbus-daemon[771]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.185' (uid=1000 pid=4626 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop dbus-daemon[771]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop gnome-shell[4626]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop gnome-shell[4626]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
Sep 12 23:48:05 ***-desktop gnome-shell[4626]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.91/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Sep 12 23:48:06 ***-desktop gnome-shell[4626]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore was not provided by any .service files
Sep 12 23:48:06 ***-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4626]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).
Sep 12 23:48:06 ***-desktop gnome-shell[4626]: GNOME Shell started at Wed Sep 12 2018 23:48:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop kernel: [  713.519783] gnome-shell[4626]: segfault at 758127e0 ip b6ba22a6 sp bfd59dc8 error 4 in libc-2.27.so[b6b0b000+1d5000]
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gnome-session[3416]: gnome-session-binary[3416]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gnome-session-binary[3416]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gnome-session[3416]: gnome-session-binary[3416]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gnome-session-binary[3416]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gnome-session-binary[3416]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gnome-session[3416]: gnome-session-binary[3416]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gnome-session-binary[3416]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop kernel: [  713.650841] rfkill: input handler enabled
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop at-spi-bus-launcher[3527]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop at-spi-bus-launcher[3527]:       after 2935 requests (2935 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-xsettings[3701]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-clipboard[3717]: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-wacom[3707]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-color[3718]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-keyboard[3727]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-media-keys[3731]: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop nautilus-deskto[3775]: nautilus-desktop: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-power[3678]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop nautilus[3818]: nautilus: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (**) Option "fd" "20"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (**) Option "fd" "23"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (**) Option "fd" "24"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (**) Option "fd" "28"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop update-notifier[4286]: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) event3  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device removed
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (**) Option "fd" "29"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) event5  - Logitech USB Keyboard: device removed
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (**) Option "fd" "30"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) event8  - Logitech USB Keyboard: device removed
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:72
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-color[1120]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Samsung_Electric_Company_SyncMaster_H9XQ119073_***_1000
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop gsd-color[1120]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Samsung_Electric_Company_SyncMaster_HMDL622064_***_1000
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "wacom"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "wacom"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:71
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "wacom"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVLeaveVT is called.
Sep 12 23:48:10 ***-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3401]: (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0206] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0213] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0216] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0220] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0224] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0226] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0229] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0231] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0234] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0236] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0239] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0242] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0246] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0250] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0253] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:11 ***-desktop NetworkManager[824]:   [1536788891.0257] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/3688/status”: No such file or directory
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped target Default.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Evolution address book service...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Zeitgeist full-text search indexer...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Zeitgeist activity log service...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Evolution calendar service...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Evolution source registry...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop zeitgeist-fts[4247]: zeitgeist-fts.vala:252: The connection is closed
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Evolution calendar service.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Evolution source registry.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Evolution address book service.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Zeitgeist full-text search indexer.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop zeitgeist-daemon[4241]: #033[31m[21:48:15.977447 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:454: La connexion est fermée
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Zeitgeist activity log service.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped target Basic System.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped target Paths.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped target Sockets.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Reached target Shutdown.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Starting Exit the Session...
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Stopped target Timers.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[3383]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 4687 (kill).
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Sep 12 23:48:15 ***-desktop systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of ***.
```

Comment: @Graham, thanks for the corrections :D sorry for my bad english

Comment: My Wacom Intuos works perfectly in 18.04 without any freezing or crashing. Note the *exact* time of a crash, and then review your logs in /var/log for that time to see what is happening. If you find suspicious log entries, edit your question to show them to us.

Comment: @user535733, thanks for taking a look, I edited my question with logs